# Fit background image to border HTML/CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I am making a test webpage to learn html/css. I would like to make the image mold to the shape of the border. It should not be much of a problem but it seems as though the image in not centered in the border. As I change the image  size etc it seems as though the image is more so in the middle of the page and leaves the border etc. I just want it to fit perfectly in the border, and for the photo to be clipped along the borders edges. I am having problems with this.

How can I make it so that the image is directly centers and fills the entire border without the middle of the photo or the majority of the photo being left outside of the border?

```css
#pic {
    float:right;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#bod {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    border: 5px ridge blue;
    float:right;
    border-radius: 105px 105px 0px 0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-image: url("smile.jpg");
    background-size: 800px 800px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bod">
    <div id="pic">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've taken the irrelevant stuff out of your question. What's the purpose of the transform? All this would be pretty simple if you put the image on `#bod` as a background. Is that an option?

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/jys4hgo2/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS for your `#bod` selector to the following:

```
#bod {
    border-radius: 105px 105px 0px 0px;
    border: 5px ridge blue;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url("smile.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

Just to be clear, I've removed the `background-attachment` attribute from the style definition and changed the value of the `background-size` attribute to `cover`, which is the important part.

**Update**

You've previously set the image through your CSS by setting the `background-image` to `url("smile.jpg")` in the `#bod` styling. I'm guessing that line isn't needed anymore since you're now setting the image in your HTML with: `<img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/500" />` instead.

That image is now off-center, to fix that change your `#pic` styling to the following:

```
#pic {
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've added the `transform-origin`, `width` and `height` attributes to the `#pic` styling.

Comment: It's off-center because of `transform: rotate(90deg);` in your `#pic` styling, I didn't notice that before since you didn't set an image in the `img` tag, but in the `#bod` styling through the `background-image` attribute instead. @isherwood are you setting the image in HTML: `<img src="HERE" />` or in  CSS?

Comment: Yup. Did you assume that wasn't relevant?

Comment: @isherwood I've updated my comment. How are you setting the image? Through HTML or CSS?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. Did you look at the demo I linked? I just substituted your code for the OP's.

Comment: @isherwood I've updated my answer. I'm guessing this is what you want. Edit: I just realized that you are not the OP :).

Answer (score 0):

The center of rotation is middle of div, so you have to make sure that the center is in the right place. You should just do this:

```
#pic {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#pic img{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebc5yjzu/3/